# How to skip python dependency with node sass installation?

Tags: npm, sass, node-gyp, node-sass

When I install `node-sass` for compiling my sass files. It asks for installing python2.7 on the windows machine for `node-gyp`.

So, Is there any option to skip the `python` dependency and work without it?